# Insert new data in the table without deleting existing data

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, sql-insert

I have a table with more than three million records, each one has a unique field **c_document**, I need to update the table with an equal one, but the new table has new records, and I cannot delete the records that already exist.
Practically this table every three months they pass me this updated table with new records, and I need to add only the new ones in my DB.
Is there a way something if not exist insert, if exist no insert but to do it at once? The sql file is 500MB.

Thanks for you help

```
TABLE

c_id
c_laname
c_mname
c_fname
c_document
c_email
c_dob
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `on duplicate key`. First, you need a unique constraint (or primary key constraint) on column `c_document`.

Then, you can insert from `source_table` to `target_table` like so:

```
insert into target_table (c_id, c_lname, c_mname, c_fname, c_document, c_email, c_dob)
select c_id, c_lname, c_mname, c_fname, c_document, c_email, c_dob
from source_table
on duplicate key update c_document = values(c_document)
```

The `update` clause is basically a no-op: we know already that `c_document` is the same on the source and target row, since that's what defines the conflict.

You could also use `insert ignore` - but I am not a big fan of this syntax, as it basically ignore all errors, not only those related to a duplicate key:

```
insert ignore into target_table (c_id, c_lname, c_mname, c_fname, c_document, c_email, c_dob)
select c_id, c_lname, c_mname, c_fname, c_document, c_email, c_dob
from source_table
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option to insert not-existig rows

```
insert into target table (c_id, c_lname, c_mname, c_fname, c_document, c_email, c_dob)
select (c_id, c_lname, c_mname, c_fname, c_document, c_email, c_dob) 
from source_table s
where not exists
    (select 1 from target_table t where t.c_document=s.c_document);
```

Not sure how it performs with millions of rows.